# Sqoop merge fails when column contains new line character

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, mapr

Ran Sqoop with options:   --fields-terminated-by '\001' --optionally-enclosed-by '\003'

Ran it twice to create 2 directories.  This created a QueryResult.java with following line:

private final DelimiterSet __inputDelimiters = new DelimiterSet((char) 1, (char) 10, (char) 3, (char) 0, false);

So far so good!

Used this QueryResult class to run a 'Sqoop Merge' but when it comes to the column that follows the column with new line character, it dies with the exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Sqoop version:
Sqoop 1.4.4-mapr
git commit id 16d0124c5b5f7bc68b8f67fbe77f0c91d46d64c1
Compiled by root on Wed Aug 28 17:22:49 PDT 2013

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue.  Fixed it by adding  --hive-drop-import-delims option.  Hope this helps someone.  Thanks.